# How o identify Internal server error motivations from asp in TIdHttp using Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, http, response

That´s a simple question,

When I receive a Internal Server Error, from HTTP protocol, running a ASP script for example I receive the motivations for that error. On ASP I receive the line where the problem are.

When I do a call from TIdHttp from Indy project, he trow a exception, and do not say nothing about the line error. But if I do the same call from Firefox he show me the line error inside the ASP script.

Does anybody knows here will I find that "Internal Server Error" description complement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `TIdHTTP` raises an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception, the body content of the error message is stored in the exception's `ErrorMessage` property, for example:

```
try
  IdHTTP1.Get(...);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
    // for instance, if the server returned a '500 Internal Server Error' reply, then:
    // E.ErrorCode = 500
    // E.Message = 'Internal Server Error'
    // E.ErrorMessage = the rest of the error message
  end;
  on E: Exception do begin
    // ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If Remy say water stops, I don't even need to test, just accept the answer! thank you again Remy. You are the best! Gambit